# Scala: How to double condition in indexed FOR loop?

Tags: java, scala

I have a code on Java:

```
int[] array = new int[100];

for (int k = 0; k < array.length * 2; k++) {
    // some action
}
```

In `for` loop I want to double array length and use it for iteration. But how can I get the same thing in Scala?

I was trying to use `zipWithIndex`, but it does not allow to double condition:

```
arr.zipWithIndex.foreach {
  case (el, idx) => {...}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To iterate over the index, as in your original for loop, you could just use a Range:

```
scala> val array = List("a", "b", "c")
array: List[String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> (0 until array.length * 2).foreach(println(_))
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

To get the index and element tuples you can use zipWithIndex on the original array (twice) or the twice array, depending on the desired result:

```
scala> (array.zipWithIndex ++ array.zipWithIndex).foreach{
     |   case (x, i) => println(s"$i: $x")
     | }
0: a
1: b
2: c
0: a
1: b
2: c

scala> (array ++ array).zipWithIndex.foreach{
     |   case (x, i) => println(s"$i: $x")
     | }
0: a
1: b
2: c
3: a
4: b
5: c
```

Comment: Use `0 until N` instead of `0 to N-1`.